# External SWF shifts on click

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I've got an application that has one screen where there are 8 windows moving around a faux 3D octagon in relation to the mouse position, moving back and forth to give the user the feel of being inside a round(ish) room. Each window is a separate swf that is being called into the application, and when a user clicks on a window, it opens the next view of the application. All works fine and dandy, except for one problem: some of the SWFs shift a little bit when they are clicked on.

There is a slight rollover animation for each window - the shutters of the windows slide open to reveal an image behind them.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this bug. It's odd, because each of the SWFs are exactly the same, and there is no issue with the rollovers, which triggers the timeline animation of each file. Some of the windows, unfortunately, just don't like being clicked on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A bit of elabortaion: The SWFs that are being problematic each have an animation that goes off the stage. It seems to be that on a click the SWF shifts over to the edge of the movieclip that is off the stage. I have tried editing each SWF so that the stage is wider than the animation's limit, but that got me nowhere.

Comment: To be completely honest, I doubt you're going to get much headway without showing some of the source code, this seems fairly specific.

Comment: My mistake. It was not in the code at all, but in the FLAs. I managed to solve this on my own. Thanks for reading though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the error was with the bounds of each of the prblematic FLAs. I solved this issue by simply drawing a transparent rectangle the same size as the stage in each movie. When each window was clicked on, the imported SWF shifted to edge of the moving part after it moved. With a rectangle the whole size of the movie, there was no need for things to move around, because the bounds were already set and never changing.